# how to check whether a client is connected to a tcp/ip port

Tags: java, sockets

I have scenario where there is a application(TCP-com PORT MAPPING SOFTWARE) which act as server and listens on port(2293) and maps to COM1. There is another java application where i have to check whether any client is connected on port no(2293) and if connected do some useful thing. I have to check whether this port(2293) which that software is listening is connected( not whether it is open or accessible).

Is there any method to detect this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a little unclear. You have program A listening on port 2293, and a separate java program (B) trying to see if anyone is connected?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a windows based system you should try running "netstat" from your command prompt. That should show all applications with open ports and if these ports are listening for data or not.

Comment: No i have to check only by java application

Answer (score 0):

Windows run cmd

```
netstat -an |findstr ESTABLISHED |findstr :2293
```

Linux run

```
netstat -an |grep ESTABLISHED |grep :2293
```

Answer (score 0):

That functionality should be in the server. It knows all right. There is no Java API that lets you detect that condition from outside.